# Using Joda DateTimeFormatter.withLocale() only affects the string value for am/pm, not the time format

Tags: java, locale, jodatime, date-formatting

Explicitly using `withLocale` to set the locale to German results in the am/pm string being localized in the time value, but does not convert to the 24 hour time format which is correct for that locale.

When a new process is created, with the `Locale.setLocale(Locale.GERMAN);` having been done, the format is correct.

Shouldn't `withLocale()` affect all aspects of the locale in question?

```
// Code snippet where call is being made:
Log.d(TAG, "XYZZY getDefault(): " + Locale.getDefault().toString());
DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormat.shortTime()
          .withLocale(Locale.getDefault());
Log.d(TAG, "XYZZY timeFormat.locale: " +
           timeFormat.getLocale().toString());
dateString = alarmTime.toString(timeFormat);
Log.d(TAG, "XYZZY dateString: "+ dateString);
```

When the variable `alarmTime` has a value of 11:00pm (2300 hours):

> 10-04 14:17:41.492 (23609): XYZZY getDefault(): en_US
>   10-04 14:17:41.493 (23609): XYZZY timeFormat.locale: en_US
>   10-04 14:17:41.495 (23609): XYZZY dateString: 11:00 PM

Now switch over to German locale and reexecute the same code, note the 
string for 'PM' changes to German, but not the time format (the suffix 
should be suppressed and the time value should be 23:00):

> 10-04 14:18:15.066 (23609): XYZZY getDefault(): de_DE
>   10-04 14:18:15.066 (23609): XYZZY timeFormat.locale: de_DE
>   10-04 14:18:15.067 (23609): XYZZY dateString: 11:00 nachm.

Wait for the process to go away and be restarted, leaving the locale as
German, and now the correct time format for German is returned:

> 10-04 14:18:54.497 (23881): XYZZY getDefault(): de_DE
>   10-04 14:18:54.497 (23881): XYZZY timeFormat.locale: de_DE
>   10-04 14:18:54.498 (23881): XYZZY dateString: 23:00

Comment: How are u creating alarmTime each time? And in the parenthesis is the number the process id? why is it the same for the case 1 and case 2 if you have re-executed your code again?

Comment: That the process id is the same is the basic problem I am seeing. When the process goes away and a new one starts (with locale set to German), I am getting the desired result (case 3).

Comment: could u share the code where you are creating the alarmTime?And, are u developing for Android?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Not an answer, since I'm **unable to reproduce**, but written as answer to show detail of how I tried to reproduce problem.*

I'm running with locale `en_US` in time zone `America/New_York`, using JDK 1.8.0_91 and **Joda-Time 2.9.9**.

*Test*

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("23:00");
System.out.println(time);
System.out.println(time.toString(DateTimeFormat.shortTime()));
System.out.println(time.toString(DateTimeFormat.shortTime().withLocale(Locale.GERMANY)));
```

*Output*

```
23:00:00.000
11:00 PM
23:00
```

`shortTime()` works fine, with and without changing locale.

The JVM default locale was never changed.

Comment: Thanks for this, Andreas, I will investigate a bit more based on what you show here. I am using JDK 1.7.0_151, not sure what JodaTime version (is there a way to discover this programmatically?)

Comment: Don't know, but the jar file name usually has the version number.

Comment: @BillB You can try `DateTime.class.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion()` or `DateTime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`. Anyway, I also tried to reproduce the problem (JDK 1.7.0_80 in Eclipse), without success. Maybe it's something specific to Android.